# Seeking help to improve the quality of some code written in expl3

Tags: expl3, package-writing

I'm starting to write new packages with expl3. As there are less learning resources and examples comparing to the usual LaTeX2e, I really don't have much idea on the quality of my code (formatting, readability, convention etc.). Thus I would like to ask for your advice with a concrete example.

Below is the current version of my package `crefthe`. I'm certain that there exists better implementation, but this is what I can achieve best so far. Regardless of its purpose, could you please point out existing problems in the code (e.g. naming conventions, formatting and readability, wrong usage of user and programing level macros, etc.) and suggest some possible improvements? I am grateful for any suggestions.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {crefthe}
  {2022/02/02} {}
  {Cross referencing with proper definite articles}

\keys_define:nn {crefthe}
  {
    unknown .code:n =
      {
        \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{cleveref}
      }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions{crefthe}

\RequirePackage{cleveref}

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl {}
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_sep_tl {}
\cs_new:Nn \crefthe_case:n {#1}
\cs_new:Nn \crefthe_nochange:n {#1}

\cs_new:Nn \crefthe_atbegindocument:n {#1}
\cs_new:Nn \crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n
  {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF \@onlypreamble \@notprerr
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_atbegindocument:n \crefthe_nochange:n
      }
      {
        \cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_atbegindocument:n \AtBeginDocument
      }
    \crefthe_atbegindocument:n {#1}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\crefthe}{st-t+O{}m}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF{ #2 }
      {
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl { #4 }
      }
      {
        \IfBooleanTF{ #3 }
          {
            \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl { #4 }
          }
          {
            \str_case_e:nn { \crefthe_prep_mode:nn }
              {
                { - } { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl  { #4 } }
              }
          }
      }
    \IfBooleanTF{ #1 } { \cref*{#5} } { \cref{#5} }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Crefthe}{st-t+O{}m}
  {
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_case:n \text_titlecase:n
    \IfBooleanTF{ #2 }
      {
        \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl { #4 }
      }
      {
        \IfBooleanTF{ #3 }
          {
            \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl { #4 }
          }
          {
            \str_case_e:nn { \crefthe_prep_mode:nn }
              {
                { - } { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl  { #4 } }
              }
          }
      }
    \IfBooleanTF{ #1 } { \Cref*{#5} } { \Cref{#5} }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prep_tl {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\crefthename}{mO{}mO{}m}
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} {}
      {
        \crefname{#1}{#3}{#5}
        \cs_set:cn {cref_#1_format:nnn} {##2#3~##1##3}
        \cs_set:cn {cref_#1_format_first:nnn} {##2#5~##1##3}
      }
      {
        \crefname{#1}{\crefthemark{#2} \g_crefthe_sep_tl #3}{\crefthemark{#4} \g_crefthe_sep_tl #5}
        \cs_set:cn {cref_#1_format:nnn} {\crefthemark{#2} \g_crefthe_sep_tl ##2#3~##1##3}
        \cs_set:cn {cref_#1_format_first:nnn} {\crefthemark{#4} \g_crefthe_sep_tl ##2#5~##1##3}
      }
    \crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc {cref@#1@format} {cref_#1_format:nnn}
        \cs_set_eq:cc {cref@#1@format@first} {cref_#1_format_first:nnn}
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Crefthename}{mO{}mO{}m}
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} {}
      {
        \Crefname{#1}{#3}{#5}
        \cs_set:cn {Cref_#1_format:nnn} {##2#3~##1##3}
        \cs_set:cn {Cref_#1_format_first:nnn} {##2#5~##1##3}
      }
      {
        \Crefname{#1}{\crefthemark{#2} \g_crefthe_sep_tl #3}{\crefthemark{#4} \g_crefthe_sep_tl #5}
        \cs_set:cn {Cref_#1_format:nnn} {\crefthemark{#2} \g_crefthe_sep_tl ##2#3~##1##3}
        \cs_set:cn {Cref_#1_format_first:nnn} {\crefthemark{#4} \g_crefthe_sep_tl ##2#5~##1##3}
      }
    \crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc {Cref@#1@format} {Cref_#1_format:nnn}
        \cs_set_eq:cc {Cref@#1@format@first} {Cref_#1_format_first:nnn}
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\crefthemark}{m}{
    \crefthe_contraction:nn { \crefthe_case:n \g_crefthe_prep_tl }
      {
        \crefthe_contraction:nn { \crefthe_case:n \g_crefthe_prepf_tl }{#1}
      }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl {}
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_crefthe_prep_tl { \text_lowercase:n \g_crefthe_prep_tl }
    \str_case_e:nnF {\str_tail:n {#1}}
      {
        {'} { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_sep_tl {} }
      }
      { \tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_sep_tl {~} }
    \cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_case:n \crefthe_nochange:n
    % \cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_case:n \text_lowercase:n
}

\cs_set:Npn \crefthe_prep_mode:nn {
    \str_case_e:nn { \languagename }
    {
      {french}        { + }
      {italian}       { + }
      {spanish}       { - }
      {portuguese}    { + }
      {brazilian}     { + }
    }
}

\cs_set:Npn \crefthe_contraction:nn #1#2
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF {#1} {}
      {#2}
      {
        \str_case_e:nn { \languagename }
          {
            {french}
              {
                \str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
                  {
                    {à~le}      {au}
                    {à~les}     {aux}
                    {de~le}     {du}
                    {de~les}    {des}
                    {À~le}      {Au}
                    {À~les}     {Aux}
                    {De~le}     {Du}
                    {De~les}    {Des}
                  }
                  {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
              }
            {italian}
              {
                \str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
                  {
                    {a~il}      {al}
                    {a~lo}      {allo}
                    {a~l'}      {all'}
                    {a~la}      {alla}
                    {di~il}     {del}
                    {di~lo}     {dello}
                    {di~l'}     {dell'}
                    {di~la}     {della}
                    {da~il}     {dal}
                    {da~lo}     {dallo}
                    {da~l'}     {dall'}
                    {da~la}     {dalla}
                    {in~il}     {nel}
                    {in~lo}     {nello}
                    {in~l'}     {nell'}
                    {in~la}     {nella}
                    {su~il}     {sul}
                    {su~lo}     {sullo}
                    {su~l'}     {sull'}
                    {su~la}     {sulla}
                    {a~i}       {ai}
                    {a~gli}     {agli}
                    {a~le}      {alle}
                    {di~i}      {dei}
                    {di~gli}    {degli}
                    {di~le}     {delle}
                    {da~i}      {dai}
                    {da~gli}    {dagli}
                    {da~le}     {dalle}
                    {in~i}      {nei}
                    {in~gli}    {negli}
                    {in~le}     {nelle}
                    {su~i}      {sui}
                    {su~gli}    {sugli}
                    {su~le}     {sulle}
                    {A~il}      {Al}
                    {A~lo}      {Allo}
                    {A~l'}      {All'}
                    {A~la}      {Alla}
                    {Di~il}     {Del}
                    {Di~lo}     {Dello}
                    {Di~l'}     {Dell'}
                    {Di~la}     {Della}
                    {Da~il}     {Dal}
                    {Da~lo}     {Dallo}
                    {Da~l'}     {Dall'}
                    {Da~la}     {Dalla}
                    {In~il}     {Nel}
                    {In~lo}     {Nello}
                    {In~l'}     {Nell'}
                    {In~la}     {Nella}
                    {Su~il}     {Sul}
                    {Su~lo}     {Sullo}
                    {Su~l'}     {Sull'}
                    {Su~la}     {Sulla}
                    {A~i}       {Ai}
                    {A~gli}     {Agli}
                    {A~le}      {Alle}
                    {Di~i}      {Dei}
                    {Di~gli}    {Degli}
                    {Di~le}     {Delle}
                    {Da~i}      {Dai}
                    {Da~gli}    {Dagli}
                    {Da~le}     {Dalle}
                    {In~i}      {Nei}
                    {In~gli}    {Negli}
                    {In~le}     {Nelle}
                    {Su~i}      {Sui}
                    {Su~gli}    {Sugli}
                    {Su~le}     {Sulle}
                  }
                  {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
              }
            {portuguese}
              {
                \str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
                  {
                    {a~o}       {ao}
                    {a~a}       {à}
                    {a~os}      {aos}
                    {a~as}      {às}
                    {de~o}      {do}
                    {de~a}      {da}
                    {de~os}     {dos}
                    {de~as}     {das}
                    {em~o}      {no}
                    {em~a}      {na}
                    {em~os}     {nos}
                    {em~as}     {nas}
                    {A~o}       {Ao}
                    {A~a}       {À}
                    {A~os}      {Aos}
                    {A~as}      {Às}
                    {De~o}      {Do}
                    {De~a}      {Da}
                    {De~os}     {Dos}
                    {De~as}     {Das}
                    {Em~o}      {No}
                    {Em~a}      {Na}
                    {Em~os}     {Nos}
                    {Em~as}     {Nas}
                  }
                  {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
              }
            {brazilian}
              {
                \str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
                  {
                    {a~o}       {ao}
                    {a~a}       {à}
                    {a~os}      {aos}
                    {a~as}      {às}
                    {de~o}      {do}
                    {de~a}      {da}
                    {de~os}     {dos}
                    {de~as}     {das}
                    {em~o}      {no}
                    {em~a}      {na}
                    {em~os}     {nos}
                    {em~as}     {nas}
                    {A~o}       {Ao}
                    {A~a}       {À}
                    {A~os}      {Aos}
                    {A~as}      {Às}
                    {De~o}      {Do}
                    {De~a}      {Da}
                    {De~os}     {Dos}
                    {De~as}     {Das}
                    {Em~o}      {No}
                    {Em~a}      {Na}
                    {Em~os}     {Nos}
                    {Em~as}     {Nas}
                  }
                  {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
              }
            {spanish}
              {
                \str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
                  {
                    {a~el}      {al}
                    {de~el}     {del}
                    {A~el}      {Al}
                    {De~el}     {Del}
                  }
                  {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: For `expl3` best practices, besides the documentation of course (`texdoc interface3`), digging the `siunitx` source is a great place to learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format of TeX-sx isn't great for review, and it's also hard to make a *general* answer. Working within those constraints:

- Generally, don't over-optimise your code. Unless you are writing very tight loops to be used 100s of times per page, you can afford to use 'higher level' abstractions.
- Read up on `l3style-guide` about spacing code, *etc.*: although it's not vital, we have a 'fixed' style for the kernel files and it's a bit easier if packages use the same style.
- Avoid bracing N-type arguments. You don't need braces around the command name after `\NewDocumentCommand` or the boolean token after `\IfBooleanTF`, for example.
- Variables should be declared before use, so for example `\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_prepf_tl {}` should be preceded by `\tl_new:N \g_crefthe_prepf_tl`. Most of the time, you should also do something similar when creating functions, so `\cs_new:Npn` or whatever at the top level, with `\cs_set:Npn` or similar if you adjust the meaning of a function inside a scope.
- Only documented material should be given public names: whilst it is not 100% clear what you want to document, I think for example `\g_crefthe_prepf_tl` should be internal so `\g__crefthe_prepf_tl`.
- Use global scope only when required: again, I'm not 100% sure here but I suspect that `\g_crefthe_prepf_tl`, *etc.* could be local.
- Track the expansion status of your commands. If you have a function that uses *any* non-expandable code, it is itself non-expandable and should be `protected`. For example, `\crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n` uses `\cs_gset_eq:NN`, which is non-expandable so `\crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n` should be defined using `\cs_new_protected:Nn` (or `\cs_new_protected:Npn` - the choice here is to some extent personal preference).
- Get the argument specifications of your functions right. You have for example `\crefthe_prep_mode:nn` which takes no arguments but which has an `:nn` signature.
- Do not rely on side-effects of implementation, and use the highest-level expansion control you can unless there is a significant performance issue. You have `\str_case_e:nn { \crefthe_prep_mode:nn }`, which abuses the fact that you've defined `\crefthe_prep_mode:nn` and that it's really a string. It would be better to have for example `\str_case:Vn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_str` where the string is created as you already do for `\crefthe_prep_mode:nn`. Notice I've used a `V`-type expansion as that's clearer and more controlled than either `e` or `o` type here. Another example of this is `\tl_gset:Nx \g_crefthe_prep_tl { \text_lowercase:n \g_crefthe_prep_tl }`, where you've relied on the fact that `\text_lowercase:n` will expand the argument: I'd favour passing as a `V`-type.
- Similarly, use the right tool for the job: `\str_if_eq:eeTF {#2} {}` is almost certainly better as `\tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}` for example (or if you *really* need that expansion, create the variant and use `\tl_if_blank:eTF`).
- Store data outside of functions. In `\crefthe_contraction:nn` you've put all of the language data inside the function. That makes changing hard for users or for you in the future. Better would be to create data structures so the information is stored outside and you dynamically find it, *e.g.* `\tl_if_exist:cTF { g__crefthe_lang_  \languagename _tl }`, probably with one or more auxiliaries to avoid having to regenerate the name repeatedly. (For example, you have `\str_case_e:nnF {#1~\text_lowercase:n{#2}}` for each language, whereas I'd do that once up front and pass the entire thing to an auxiliary.)
- Be wary of `\cs_(g)set_eq:NN` when other methods are available. With  for example `\cs_gset_eq:NN \crefthe_case:n \text_titlecase:n`, if you need to trace the code you'll never 'see' `\text_titlecase:n`. If on the other hand you have `\cs_gset:Npn \crefthe_case:n ##1 { \text_titlecase:n {##1} }` you'll find debugging much easier. The performance hit of one expansion is typically not an issue outside of very tight loops.
- Be careful not to overuse `ltcmd`'s ability to make complex interfaces. Almost always, signatures should look something like `som` or `sO{}m`. For example, you have `\NewDocumentCommand{\Crefthe}{st-t+O{}m}`, which uses non-standard tokens (not stars) for altering behaviour.
- Write public code-level interfaces and uses them to implement document commands. There should be minimal 'programming' in the document command code, just enough to split out different paths based on the optional parts of the signature. For any substantive new `expl3` code, there should be a programmers API providing code-level ways to get to the *functionality* but not using the document commands (*e.g.* separate functions for places that at a document level you use optional arguments).
- As far as possible, stick to LaTeX2e conventions; I'm really not sure what you are up to with `\crefthe_atbegindocument_if_needed:n`, but my immediate thought is that you are trying to subvert the idea that declarations have to be in the preamble, with only usage of declared material in the document body

Comment: Thank you for these detailed reminds! Regarding your third advice, does it mean that I should just write `\IfBooleanTF #1` and `\NewDocumentCommand \CommandName`?

Comment: @Jinwen Yes, exactly: in both cases you can only give a single token as an argument

Comment: Following your 9th advice (*Do not rely on side-effects of implementation*), I would like to change `\crefthe_prep_mode:` into `\l__crefthe_prep_mode_str`. What I don't understand is that instead of `\cs_set:Nn`, how should a dynamical string be declared? Should I use `\tl_set:Nn` here?

Comment: @Jinwen If you want something dynamic, you will want a function not a `tl` (it's a value judgement, of course) - what I would do is give it the right signature. But I do wonder if the setup is quite right...