# On the improper expl3 syntax in the code of "crefthe"

Tags: expl3, package-writing, crefthe

As I'm very new to `expl3`, the first package I wrote with it, `crefthe`, has a lot improper syntax. Thanks to Joseph Wright's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632495) and @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633246), I've managed to corrected a few, but surely there remains more. The current version is listed in the end.

Here are two problems that has been pointed out by @egreg that I couldn't fix:

1. Changing `\exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn` to `\str_case:Vn` breaks the functionality (the prepositions disappear), this is probably due to the `\str_case_e:nn { \languagename }` inside `\l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl`, but I'm not sure.
2. Changing `\text_lowercase:n` to `\str_foldcase:n` also breaks the article contraction functionality, and even if I extend it to use `\str_foldcase:x` the article contraction still won't work correctly. (By the way, may I assume `\text_lowercase:n` shall always expand its argument, or is it better to create a `:x` variant and use this to be certain?)

Please do not hesitate to tell me if you find any improper usage of `expl3` or if you have better idea for the implementation. Thank you in advance!

---

Below is a test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,french]{crefthe}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{thmn}{Théorème facile}

\crefthename{thm}[le]{théorème}[les]{théorèmes}
\crefthename{thmn}[le]{théorème facile}[les]{théorèmes faciles}

\Crefthename{thm}[Le]{théorème}[Les]{théorèmes}
\Crefthename{thmn}[Le]{théorème facile}[Les]{théorèmes faciles}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
    some text.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm2}
    more text.
\end{thm}

\begin{thmn}\label{thmn1}
    more other text.
\end{thmn}


- Single one -

\crefthe[\`A]{thm1}, \crefthe[\`a]{thm1}

\crefthe[À]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\Crefthe[à]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\crefthe[de]{thm1}

\Crefthe[de]{thm1}


- Multiple ones -

\crefthe[À]{thm1,thmn1}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1,thmn1}

\crefthe[À]{thm1,thm2}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1,thm2}

\Crefthe[De]{thm1,thm2,thmn1}

\Crefthe{thm1,thm2,thmn1}

\crefthe{thm1,thm2}


\end{document}
```

The correct result should be:

[image]

Current version (2022-02-09) of `crefthe`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {crefthe}
  {2022/02/09} {}
  {Cross referencing with proper definite articles}

\keys_define:nn { crefthe }
  {
    , overwrite .bool_set:N = \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
    , overwrite .initial:n  = { false }
    , unknown .code:n       =
        {
          \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { cleveref }
        }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { crefthe }

\RequirePackage { cleveref }

\cs_set_eq:cc { crefthe_cref_original:w }     { cref }
\cs_set_eq:cc { crefthe_Cref_original:w }     { Cref }
\cs_set_eq:cc { crefthe_crefname_original:w } { crefname }
\cs_set_eq:cc { crefthe_Crefname_original:w } { Crefname }

\bool_if:NT \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
  {
    \hook_gput_next_code:nn { package/crefthe/after }
      {
        % \RenewCommandCopy \cref     \crefthe
        % \RenewCommandCopy \Cref     \Crefthe
        % \RenewCommandCopy \crefname \crefthename
        % \RenewCommandCopy \Crefname \Crefthename
        \cs_set_eq:cc { cref }     { crefthe }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { Cref }     { Crefthe }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { crefname } { crefthename }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { Crefname } { Crefthename }
      }
  }

\tl_new:N \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl
\tl_new:N \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl

\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl

\bool_new:N \g__crefthe_uppercase_bool

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \g__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \bool_if:nTF { #2 }
      {
        \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 }
      }
      {
        \bool_if:nTF { #3 }
          {
            \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl { #4 }
          }
          {
            \exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl
              {
                { - } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl  { #4 } }
              }
          }
      }
    \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { \crefthe_cref_original:w * { #5 } } { \crefthe_cref_original:w { #5 } }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \g__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \bool_if:nTF { #2 }
      {
        \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 }
      }
      {
        \bool_if:nTF { #3 }
          {
            \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl { #4 }
          }
          {
            \exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl
              {
                { - } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl  { #4 } }
              }
          }
      }
    \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { \crefthe_Cref_original:w * { #5 } } { \crefthe_Cref_original:w { #5 } }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl {}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { #2 }
      {
        \crefthe_crefname_original:w { #1 } { #3 } { #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { cref_#1_format:nnn } { ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { cref_#1_format_first:nnn } { ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
      {
        \crefthe_crefname_original:w { #1 } { \crefthemark{ #2 } #3 } { \crefthemark{ #4 } #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { cref_#1_format:nnn } { \crefthemark { #2 } ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { cref_#1_format_first:nnn } { \crefthemark { #4 } ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { crefthe }
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc { cref@ #1 @format } { cref_#1_format:nnn }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { cref@ #1 @format@first } { cref_#1_format_first:nnn }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { #2 }
      {
        \crefthe_Crefname_original:w { #1 } { #3 } { #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { Cref_#1_format:nnn } { ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { Cref_#1_format_first:nnn } { ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
      {
        \crefthe_Crefname_original:w { #1 } { \crefthemark{ #2 } #3 }{ \crefthemark{ #4 } #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { Cref_#1_format:nnn } { \crefthemark { #2 } ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { Cref_#1_format_first:nnn } { \crefthemark { #4 } ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { crefthe }
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc { Cref@ #1 @format } { Cref_#1_format:nnn }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { Cref@ #1 @format@first } { Cref_#1_format_first:nnn }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthemark { m }
  {
    \crefthe_contraction:nn { \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl }
      {
        \crefthe_contraction:nn { \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl } { #1 }
      }
    \tl_gset:Nn \g__crefthe_prep_once_tl {}
    \tl_gset:Nx \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl { \text_lowercase:n \g__crefthe_prep_each_tl }
    \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_tail:n { #1 } } { ' } { ~ }
    \bool_set_false:N \g__crefthe_uppercase_bool
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case_e:nn { nv } { p, T, F, TF }

\tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl {
  \str_case_e:nn { \languagename }
    {
      {french}        { + }
      {italian}       { + }
      {spanish}       { - }
      {portuguese}    { + }
      {brazilian}     { + }
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \crefthe_contraction:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_if_blank:eTF { #1 }
      { #2 }
      {
        \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \g__crefthe_uppercase_bool
              {
                \str_case_e:nvF { #1 ~ \text_lowercase:n { #2 } }
                { g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_ \languagename _tl }
                { #1 ~ \text_lowercase:n { #2 } }
              }
              {
                \str_case_e:nvF { #1 ~ \text_lowercase:n { #2 } }
                { g_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
                { #1 ~ \text_lowercase:n { #2 } }
              }
          }
          { #1 ~ #2 }
      }
  }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl
  {
    { à~le }      { au }
    { à~les }     { aux }
    { de~le }     { du }
    { de~les }    { des }
    { À~le }      { Au }
    { À~les }     { Aux }
    { De~le }     { Du }
    { De~les }    { Des }
  }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_french_tl
  {
    { à~le }      { Au }
    { à~les }     { Aux }
    { de~le }     { Du }
    { de~les }    { Des }
    { À~le }      { Au }
    { À~les }     { Aux }
    { De~le }     { Du }
    { De~les }    { Des }
  }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_italian_tl
  {
    { a~il }      { al }
    { a~lo }      { allo }
    { a~l' }      { all' }
    { a~la }      { alla }
    { di~il }     { del }
    { di~lo }     { dello }
    { di~l' }     { dell' }
    { di~la }     { della }
    { da~il }     { dal }
    { da~lo }     { dallo }
    { da~l' }     { dall' }
    { da~la }     { dalla }
    { in~il }     { nel }
    { in~lo }     { nello }
    { in~l' }     { nell' }
    { in~la }     { nella }
    { su~il }     { sul }
    { su~lo }     { sullo }
    { su~l' }     { sull' }
    { su~la }     { sulla }
    { a~i }       { ai }
    { a~gli }     { agli }
    { a~le }      { alle }
    { di~i }      { dei }
    { di~gli }    { degli }
    { di~le }     { delle }
    { da~i }      { dai }
    { da~gli }    { dagli }
    { da~le }     { dalle }
    { in~i }      { nei }
    { in~gli }    { negli }
    { in~le }     { nelle }
    { su~i }      { sui }
    { su~gli }    { sugli }
    { su~le }     { sulle }
    { A~il }      { Al }
    { A~lo }      { Allo }
    { A~l' }      { All' }
    { A~la }      { Alla }
    { Di~il }     { Del }
    { Di~lo }     { Dello }
    { Di~l' }     { Dell' }
    { Di~la }     { Della }
    { Da~il }     { Dal }
    { Da~lo }     { Dallo }
    { Da~l' }     { Dall' }
    { Da~la }     { Dalla }
    { In~il }     { Nel }
    { In~lo }     { Nello }
    { In~l' }     { Nell' }
    { In~la }     { Nella }
    { Su~il }     { Sul }
    { Su~lo }     { Sullo }
    { Su~l' }     { Sull' }
    { Su~la }     { Sulla }
    { A~i }       { Ai }
    { A~gli }     { Agli }
    { A~le }      { Alle }
    { Di~i }      { Dei }
    { Di~gli }    { Degli }
    { Di~le }     { Delle }
    { Da~i }      { Dai }
    { Da~gli }    { Dagli }
    { Da~le }     { Dalle }
    { In~i }      { Nei }
    { In~gli }    { Negli }
    { In~le }     { Nelle }
    { Su~i }      { Sui }
    { Su~gli }    { Sugli }
    { Su~le }     { Sulle }
  }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_italian_tl
  {
    { a~il }      { Al }
    { a~lo }      { Allo }
    { a~l' }      { All' }
    { a~la }      { Alla }
    { di~il }     { Del }
    { di~lo }     { Dello }
    { di~l' }     { Dell' }
    { di~la }     { Della }
    { da~il }     { Dal }
    { da~lo }     { Dallo }
    { da~l' }     { Dall' }
    { da~la }     { Dalla }
    { in~il }     { Nel }
    { in~lo }     { Nello }
    { in~l' }     { Nell' }
    { in~la }     { Nella }
    { su~il }     { Sul }
    { su~lo }     { Sullo }
    { su~l' }     { Sull' }
    { su~la }     { Sulla }
    { a~i }       { Ai }
    { a~gli }     { Agli }
    { a~le }      { Alle }
    { di~i }      { Dei }
    { di~gli }    { Degli }
    { di~le }     { Delle }
    { da~i }      { Dai }
    { da~gli }    { Dagli }
    { da~le }     { Dalle }
    { in~i }      { Nei }
    { in~gli }    { Negli }
    { in~le }     { Nelle }
    { su~i }      { Sui }
    { su~gli }    { Sugli }
    { su~le }     { Sulle }
    { A~il }      { Al }
    { A~lo }      { Allo }
    { A~l' }      { All' }
    { A~la }      { Alla }
    { Di~il }     { Del }
    { Di~lo }     { Dello }
    { Di~l' }     { Dell' }
    { Di~la }     { Della }
    { Da~il }     { Dal }
    { Da~lo }     { Dallo }
    { Da~l' }     { Dall' }
    { Da~la }     { Dalla }
    { In~il }     { Nel }
    { In~lo }     { Nello }
    { In~l' }     { Nell' }
    { In~la }     { Nella }
    { Su~il }     { Sul }
    { Su~lo }     { Sullo }
    { Su~l' }     { Sull' }
    { Su~la }     { Sulla }
    { A~i }       { Ai }
    { A~gli }     { Agli }
    { A~le }      { Alle }
    { Di~i }      { Dei }
    { Di~gli }    { Degli }
    { Di~le }     { Delle }
    { Da~i }      { Dai }
    { Da~gli }    { Dagli }
    { Da~le }     { Dalle }
    { In~i }      { Nei }
    { In~gli }    { Negli }
    { In~le }     { Nelle }
    { Su~i }      { Sui }
    { Su~gli }    { Sugli }
    { Su~le }     { Sulle }
  }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_spanish_tl
  {
    { a~el }      { al }
    { de~el }     { del }
    { A~el }      { Al }
    { De~el }     { Del }
  }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_spanish_tl
  {
    { a~el }      { Al }
    { de~el }     { Del }
    { A~el }      { Al }
    { De~el }     { Del }
  }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_portuguese_tl
  {
    { a~o }       { ao }
    { a~a }       { à }
    { a~os }      { aos }
    { a~as }      { às }
    { de~o }      { do }
    { de~a }      { da }
    { de~os }     { dos }
    { de~as }     { das }
    { em~o }      { no }
    { em~a }      { na }
    { em~os }     { nos }
    { em~as }     { nas }
    { A~o }       { Ao }
    { A~a }       { À }
    { A~os }      { Aos }
    { A~as }      { Às }
    { De~o }      { Do }
    { De~a }      { Da }
    { De~os }     { Dos }
    { De~as }     { Das }
    { Em~o }      { No }
    { Em~a }      { Na }
    { Em~os }     { Nos }
    { Em~as }     { Nas }
  }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_portuguese_tl
  {
    { a~o }       { Ao }
    { a~a }       { À }
    { a~os }      { Aos }
    { a~as }      { Às }
    { de~o }      { Do }
    { de~a }      { Da }
    { de~os }     { Dos }
    { de~as }     { Das }
    { em~o }      { No }
    { em~a }      { Na }
    { em~os }     { Nos }
    { em~as }     { Nas }
    { A~o }       { Ao }
    { A~a }       { À }
    { A~os }      { Aos }
    { A~as }      { Às }
    { De~o }      { Do }
    { De~a }      { Da }
    { De~os }     { Dos }
    { De~as }     { Das }
    { Em~o }      { No }
    { Em~a }      { Na }
    { Em~os }     { Nos }
    { Em~as }     { Nas }
  }

\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_brazilian_tl
  {
    { a~o }       { ao }
    { a~a }       { à }
    { a~os }      { aos }
    { a~as }      { às }
    { de~o }      { do }
    { de~a }      { da }
    { de~os }     { dos }
    { de~as }     { das }
    { em~o }      { no }
    { em~a }      { na }
    { em~os }     { nos }
    { em~as }     { nas }
    { A~o }       { Ao }
    { A~a }       { À }
    { A~os }      { Aos }
    { A~as }      { Às }
    { De~o }      { Do }
    { De~a }      { Da }
    { De~os }     { Dos }
    { De~as }     { Das }
    { Em~o }      { No }
    { Em~a }      { Na }
    { Em~os }     { Nos }
    { Em~as }     { Nas }
  }
\tl_gset:Nn \g_crefthe_contraction_rule_uppercase_brazilian_tl
  {
    { a~o }       { Ao }
    { a~a }       { À }
    { a~os }      { Aos }
    { a~as }      { Às }
    { de~o }      { Do }
    { de~a }      { Da }
    { de~os }     { Dos }
    { de~as }     { Das }
    { em~o }      { No }
    { em~a }      { Na }
    { em~os }     { Nos }
    { em~as }     { Nas }
    { A~o }       { Ao }
    { A~a }       { À }
    { A~os }      { Aos }
    { A~as }      { Às }
    { De~o }      { Do }
    { De~a }      { Da }
    { De~os }     { Dos }
    { De~as }     { Das }
    { Em~o }      { No }
    { Em~a }      { Na }
    { Em~os }     { Nos }
    { Em~as }     { Nas }
  }
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `crefthe.sty'.
```

Comment: Two quick notes:  1) you can't really call `\cref` as `\crefthe_cref_original:n` because it doesn't take just an `n` argument.  `\crefthe_cref_original:w` would be more appropriate.  2) I suggest using `\RenewCommandCopy` for the `overwrite` thing, because you are not copying a simple macro, but a full command with internals and such that need to be copied along (nothing really bad happens in this case, but you asked for coding style... :).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your suggestions! May I ask about the usage of `\RenewCommandCopy`? I didn't found it in `xparse`'s documentation. Does it works like `\RenewCommandCopy \cref \crefthe`?

Comment: The syntax is `\NewCommandCopy <new name> <old name>`.  It's the same syntax as the primitive `\let`, and `\cs_set_eq:NN`, and `\LetLtxMacro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my nitpicking on your code (more or less in the order I found in the source):

1. You can't really call `\cref` as `\crefthe_cref_original:n` because it doesn't take just an `n` argument (there is the optional `*` argument). `...:Nn` is also wrong because the `*` is not mandatory. `\crefthe_cref_original:w` would be more appropriate;
2. I suggest using `\RenewCommandCopy` for the `overwrite` thing, because you are not copying a simple macro, but a full stack of macros that make up a command, with internals and such that need to be copied along (nothing really bad happens in this case, but you *asked* for coding style... :)
3. Since `overwrite` happens at the end of your package, there is no need to use the `package/crefthe/after` hook, as much as I like advertising hooks,  just put the code at the end of the package;
4. `\tl_gset:Nn <tl var> { }` is `\tl_gclear:N <tl var>`;
5. You should use `\bool_gset_false:N` with `\g__crefthe_uppercase_bool` (while writing/testing your code, you can load `expl3` with `\RequirePackage[enable-debug]{expl3}` then do `\debug_on:n { check-declarations, deprecation }` to catch this type of error);
6. Regarding `\exp_args:Nx \str_case:nn \l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl`, it works because you coded it to work, but it's conceptually wrong (twice).  First, the token list `\l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl` doesn't contain a ”static“ token list in the `expl3` sense, but an *action*: it expands to `+` or `-` depending on the value of `\languagename`, so expanding its `V`alue does not work because it requires multiple expansion steps to become something “static”.  Second, because you are then using a `\str_...` function on a `tl`, so it takes the not-completely-expanded contents of the token list and turns them into a meaningless string.  The politically correct approach here would be to make `\l__crefthe_prep_mode_tl` a function, then fully expand it first, and *then* use the returned string.  This is commented in the code;
7. `\crefthe` and `\Crefthe` are exactly the same except for the boolean at the beginning and the `\crefthe_[Cc]ref_original:w` function, so you can merge them in a `\__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN` function.  Code duplication is often *evil*!  Same for `\crefthename` and `\Crefthename`;
8. `\text_lowercase:n` is rather slow, so if a macro uses the same `\text_lowercase:n { <something> }` twice, I recommend `e`-expanding that first, then passing everything to an internal macro that uses the text already lowercase'd (I did that in `\crefthe_contraction:nn`);
9. You have to do `\tl_new:N <tl var>` before you do `\tl_(g)set:Nn <tl var> { ... }`.  Not doing that is an error (in theory).  All `\g_crefthe_contraction_rule_<language>_tl` are not declared in your code before you do `\tl_gset:Nn` on them.  These, however, never change, so they can be constants, so you can define them with `\tl_const:Nn` instead;
10. In `\crefthe_contraction:nn` you do `\tl_if_blank:eTF {#1}`, but `#1` is a `tl` variable that contains text, and it's dangerous to `e`- or `x`-expand text.  Expand the variable to its value using `V`-expansion before passing it to `\crefthe_contraction:nn`, and then use `\tl_if_blank:nTF {#1}`.  Besides, if you expand something early, you expand it as needed once, and avoid doing the same expansion multiple times later, making your code generally faster;
11. Here you have to use `\text_lowercase:n` instead of `\str_foldcase:n` because `\str_foldcase:n` doesn't work on things like `À` because it's meant for code-like strings, and not textual strings like accented characters;
12. Your code doesn't have any grouping, so there seems to be no need for global assignments, so I've made everything local;
13. Your code does something funny, that I'm not sure it's (currently) possible to change.  It manages to compare `À le` with `` \`A le `` by exploiting the fact that (in pdfTeX) the former eventually expands to the latter, but eventually both expand to (the same) gibberish and are found to be equal.  Ideally, there should be a better way to normalise `` \`A le `` to `À le` (or the other way around) and compare both;
14. You can use `\text_titlecase_first:n` to make the first letter of the contractions uppercase and avoid defining what's basically a copy of each contraction list.  Also, the `brazilian` and `portuguese` lists should be the same, so you can define only one and make a copy;

16. `\str_case:nn` (and by extension `\str_case_e:nn`) cannot have a predicate version (`\str_case_p:nn`) because it would break the boolean expression parsing in `\bool_if:nTF` by injecting arbitrary tokens in there, so generating a `_p` variant from `\str_case_e:nn` is wrong (and throws an error if you enable debugging as suggested in point 5).

That's all, I think...  Here's your code, completely destroyed :)

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{crefthe.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {crefthe}
  {2022/02/09} {}
  {Cross referencing with proper definite articles}

\keys_define:nn { crefthe }
  {
    , overwrite .bool_set:N = \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
    , overwrite .initial:n  = { false }
    , unknown .code:n       =
      { \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { cleveref } }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { crefthe }

\RequirePackage { cleveref }

\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_cref_original:w     \cref
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_Cref_original:w     \Cref
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_crefname_original:w \crefname
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_Crefname_original:w \Crefname

\str_new:N \l__crefthe_tmpa_str

\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl
\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl

\bool_new:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 {#4} {#5} \crefthe_cref_original:w
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 {#4} {#5} \crefthe_Cref_original:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6
  {
    \bool_if:NTF #2
      { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl {#4} }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF #3
          { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl {#4} }
          {
            % \str_set:Nx fully expands \__crefthe_prep_mode: into a
            % string, then \str_case:Vn compares the value of the
            % resulting string:
            \str_set:Nx \l__crefthe_tmpa_str { \__crefthe_prep_mode: }
            \str_case:Vn \l__crefthe_tmpa_str
              {
                { - } { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl {#4} }
                { + } { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl  {#4} }
              }
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF #1
      { #6 * {#5} } % here #6 is \crefthe_cref_original:w or \crefthe_Cref_original:w
      { #6   {#5} }
    \tl_gclear:N \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_prep_mode:
  {
    \str_case:Vn { \languagename }
      {
        {french}        { + }
        {italian}       { + }
        {spanish}       { - }
        {portuguese}    { + }
        {brazilian}     { + }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
      c \crefthe_crefname_original:w
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
      C \crefthe_Crefname_original:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7
  {
    % #6 is c or C
    % #7 is \crefthe_crefname_original:w or \crefthe_Crefname_original:w
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
      {
        #7 {#1} {#3} {#5}
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format:nnn } { ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn } { ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
      {
        #7 {#1} { \crefthemark {#2} #3 } { \crefthemark {#4} #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format:nnn } { \crefthemark {#2} ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn } { \crefthemark {#4} ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
    \AddToHook { begindocument }
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc { #6ref@ #1 @format } { #6ref_#1_format:nnn }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { #6ref@ #1 @format@first } { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \text_lowercase:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand \crefthemark { m }
  {
    \crefthe_contraction:Ve \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
      { \crefthe_contraction:Vn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl {#1} }
    \tl_gclear:N \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
      { \text_lowercase:V \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl }
    \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_tail:n {#1} } { ' } { ~ }
    \bool_set_false:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case_e:nn { nv } { T, F, TF }
\cs_new:Npn \crefthe_contraction:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__crefthe_contraction:nnn
      { \text_lowercase:n {#2} } {#1} {#2}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \crefthe_contraction:nn { V, Ve }
\cs_new:Npn \eshow:n #1 { \exp_args:No \use_none:n { \ERR <#1> } }
\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_contraction:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    % #1 is \text_lowercase:n {#3}
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#2}
      {#3}
      {
        \tl_if_exist:cTF { c_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
          {
            \exp_args:Ne \__crefthe_contraction_uppercase:n
              {
                % This e-expansion here is wrong, but the code doesn't work
                % without it.  See point 13 in my answer...
                %        vv
                \str_case_e:nvF { #2~#1 }
                  { c_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
                  { #2~#1 }
              }
          }
          { #2~#3 }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_contraction_uppercase:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
      { \text_titlecase_first:n }
      { \use:n }
        {#1}
  }

\bool_if:NT \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
  {
    \RenewCommandCopy \cref     \crefthe
    \RenewCommandCopy \Cref     \Crefthe
    \RenewCommandCopy \crefname \crefthename
    \RenewCommandCopy \Crefname \Crefthename
  }

\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl
  {
    { à~le }      { au }
    { à~les }     { aux }
    { de~le }     { du }
    { de~les }    { des }
    { À~le }      { Au }
    { À~les }     { Aux }
    { De~le }     { Du }
    { De~les }    { Des }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_italian_tl
  {
    { a~il }      { al }
    { a~lo }      { allo }
    { a~l' }      { all' }
    { a~la }      { alla }
    { di~il }     { del }
    { di~lo }     { dello }
    { di~l' }     { dell' }
    { di~la }     { della }
    { da~il }     { dal }
    { da~lo }     { dallo }
    { da~l' }     { dall' }
    { da~la }     { dalla }
    { in~il }     { nel }
    { in~lo }     { nello }
    { in~l' }     { nell' }
    { in~la }     { nella }
    { su~il }     { sul }
    { su~lo }     { sullo }
    { su~l' }     { sull' }
    { su~la }     { sulla }
    { a~i }       { ai }
    { a~gli }     { agli }
    { a~le }      { alle }
    { di~i }      { dei }
    { di~gli }    { degli }
    { di~le }     { delle }
    { da~i }      { dai }
    { da~gli }    { dagli }
    { da~le }     { dalle }
    { in~i }      { nei }
    { in~gli }    { negli }
    { in~le }     { nelle }
    { su~i }      { sui }
    { su~gli }    { sugli }
    { su~le }     { sulle }
    { A~il }      { Al }
    { A~lo }      { Allo }
    { A~l' }      { All' }
    { A~la }      { Alla }
    { Di~il }     { Del }
    { Di~lo }     { Dello }
    { Di~l' }     { Dell' }
    { Di~la }     { Della }
    { Da~il }     { Dal }
    { Da~lo }     { Dallo }
    { Da~l' }     { Dall' }
    { Da~la }     { Dalla }
    { In~il }     { Nel }
    { In~lo }     { Nello }
    { In~l' }     { Nell' }
    { In~la }     { Nella }
    { Su~il }     { Sul }
    { Su~lo }     { Sullo }
    { Su~l' }     { Sull' }
    { Su~la }     { Sulla }
    { A~i }       { Ai }
    { A~gli }     { Agli }
    { A~le }      { Alle }
    { Di~i }      { Dei }
    { Di~gli }    { Degli }
    { Di~le }     { Delle }
    { Da~i }      { Dai }
    { Da~gli }    { Dagli }
    { Da~le }     { Dalle }
    { In~i }      { Nei }
    { In~gli }    { Negli }
    { In~le }     { Nelle }
    { Su~i }      { Sui }
    { Su~gli }    { Sugli }
    { Su~le }     { Sulle }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_spanish_tl
  {
    { a~el }      { al }
    { de~el }     { del }
    { A~el }      { Al }
    { De~el }     { Del }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_portuguese_tl
  {
    { a~o }       { ao }
    { a~a }       { à }
    { a~os }      { aos }
    { a~as }      { às }
    { de~o }      { do }
    { de~a }      { da }
    { de~os }     { dos }
    { de~as }     { das }
    { em~o }      { no }
    { em~a }      { na }
    { em~os }     { nos }
    { em~as }     { nas }
    { A~o }       { Ao }
    { A~a }       { À }
    { A~os }      { Aos }
    { A~as }      { Às }
    { De~o }      { Do }
    { De~a }      { Da }
    { De~os }     { Dos }
    { De~as }     { Das }
    { Em~o }      { No }
    { Em~a }      { Na }
    { Em~os }     { Nos }
    { Em~as }     { Nas }
  }
\tl_const:Nx \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_brazilian_tl
  { \exp_not:V \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_portuguese_tl }
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `crefthe.sty'.
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,french]{crefthe}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newtheorem{thm}{Théorème}
\newtheorem{thmn}{Théorème facile}

\crefthename{thm}[le]{théorème}[les]{théorèmes}
\crefthename{thmn}[le]{théorème facile}[les]{théorèmes faciles}

\Crefthename{thm}[Le]{théorème}[Les]{théorèmes}
\Crefthename{thmn}[Le]{théorème facile}[Les]{théorèmes faciles}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm1}
    some text.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm2}
    more text.
\end{thm}

\begin{thmn}\label{thmn1}
    more other text.
\end{thmn}


- Single one -

\crefthe[\`A]{thm1}, \crefthe[\`a]{thm1}

\crefthe[À]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\Crefthe[à]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1}, \crefthe[à]{thm1}

\crefthe[de]{thm1}

\Crefthe[de]{thm1}


- Multiple ones -

\crefthe[À]{thm1,thmn1}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1,thmn1}

\crefthe[À]{thm1,thm2}

\Crefthe[À]{thm1,thm2}

\Crefthe[De]{thm1,thm2,thmn1}

\Crefthe{thm1,thm2,thmn1}

\crefthe{thm1,thm2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: On point 11: this was something of a value judgement as exactly what might be regarded by LaTeX programmers as 'text' versus a 'programmatic string' us tricky, and in the main I was hoping that the need to normalise say `Å`  to `å` in some filename  or code identifier would be vanishing small. It's certainly possible to imagine reworking `\str_foldcase:n` to work with UTF-8 - it would still be a lot faster than `\text_lowercase:n`, quite apart from the conceptual difference.

Comment: On point 13, we could generalise  the code in `text` module, currently needed to case change text with macro-based accents. It would be possible to move this to `\text_expand:n`, for example - the question there was whether normalising e.g. `\'a` to `á` is 'expansion'.

Comment: Thank you so much! 1) On point 14, I didn't use `\text_titlecase` (which is also why the uppercased version of contraction rules) for I thought this wouldn't work under pdfLaTeX for accent letter, but now it seems the result looks good. 2) On point 15, the code is for `\Crefthe`, so that from the second definite article, prepositions will be set to lowercase and result in the final text. However even if I uncomment the code now, this behavior is still broken. I didn't found out the reasons yet -- there is a full day's topology class waiting for me, and I shall come back to it in evening :)

Comment: @JosephWright `\text_do_this_transformation_that_we_are_not_sure_exactly_how_to_call_it:n` :)

Comment: @Jinwen 1) Yes, Joseph went to great lengths to ensure that text transformations work properly on pdfTeX. It's a lot more work than it looks like.  2) what point 15? ;-)  Sorry, I didn't notice the change in "Au ... et Au ...".  I put that line back in the code and (if I didn't miss anything) the output looks like the one in your picture.  If there's something else broken, do let me know.  Have fun with topology :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, I'm back now. I've got two questions: 1) Why is there a `\exp_args:Ne`? Also, you said in the comment that "This e-expansion here is wrong", why is that? When this `\exp_args:Ne` is removed, the test document seems to produce the same result, so is there some case in which something shall be broken without this `\exp_args:Ne`?

Comment: 2) In the "overwrite" mode, the hyperlinks are placed at wrong place (the definite articles are included), so `\cref` is not the same as `\crefthe`. Why would this happen? (I didn't notice this before, but this also happens with my old code so it is not due to `\RenewCommandCopy`)

Comment: @Jinwen Re: 1) Sorry, I wrote the comments as I was changing your code, and admittedly this part didn't make much sense.  The “this e-expansion is wrong” refers to the `\str_case_e:nvF` in your original code:  it does the equivalent of (try it) `\edef\x{\c_crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl}\show\x`, which expands the accents to encoding-specific commands (this is what I mean in point 13 of my answer), and then compares them  (this kinda makes your code work with things like `\'A` by accident :)

Comment: @Jinwen Re: 2) The `\RenewCommandCopy` change should be the most harmless of all (in the case in your package, it doesn't hurt to use `\cs_set_eq:NN`, but it may bite you in some cases).  As a rule of thumb, use `\cs_set_eq:NN` with commands defined with `\cs_new...` and when you know for sure it's safe.  When the command is defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\DeclareRobustCommand`, or when you are not sure, use `\NewCommandCopy`.  Regarding the hyperlinks, sorry, I don't know cleveref and hyperref enough to know have an easy answer

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I've learnt a good number of things from the answer, thank you.  But may I trouble you again?  ;-) I'm trying to reason with the precept of variables having to be declared before they are set, and with `degub` `check-declarations`. But what about variables which are meant to only exist within a scope, and their existence outside it makes a difference? Is this "an error (in theory)" too? (given `\tl_new:N` and friends are global). If not, is there a way to satisfy the debugger and keep "local variable's existence local" kind of behavior?

Comment: @gusbrs In `expl3` the concept of a variable that "exist locally" doesn't exist (although it is perfectly possible in TeX).  All variables are declared globally with `\<thing>_new:N` (or `\<thing>_const:Nn`), then assigned globally or locally as needed.  If you need a temporary/scratch variable with local scope, define a `\<thing>_new:N \l__mypkg_tmpa_<thing>`, and then use that when needed (yeah, sometimes that feels like a lot of work for just a temporary variable, but that's how things are :)

Comment: @gusbrs Also, for example in plain/classical LaTeX, when you do `\newcount\tmpcount`, `\tmpcount` is allocated globally, so maybe part of the design decision was based on that

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Mhmm, in my case at hand, they are not temporary variables, but options whose existence or not is meaningful. And I got plenty of those... :-(. I don't understand the reason for this, but I presume there's one. Well, I've been since yesterday trying to figure a way out of this. Let's see what comes out of it, of if I'll have to live with this "sin".  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @gusbrs I can't think of a case when the test for the existence of a variable would be required, which you couldn't solve by having the variable and, worst case scenario, a boolean that tells if it "officially" exists.  If you sketch some code, I can take a look

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Well, I have the case, in `zref-clever` I can set each option at different "scopes" (general, per type, per language, etc), and some precedence rules to which scope applies first. And this is decided by "existence". But I wouldn't ask for "code review", you have more important stuff at hand and, even if not at the moment, it is my job. Yeah, my best idea so far was to keep a separate boolean to keep track of the "status" of the variable. But it seems a waste, specially since I do not understand the reason for the restriction...

Comment: @gusbrs You can have a separate boolean, or, still following the rules, initialise your token lists (if they are `tl` variables, of course) to something that can't be input (without malicious intent), for example: `\tl_set:Nx \l__zrefclever_option_tl { a \token_to_str:N a }`.  The token list would contain a catcode 11 `a`, followed by a catcode 12 `a`.  You could simply test that with `\if_meaning:w` against another token list that contains such "impossible" combination (and it would be (marginally) faster than testing for existence :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Mostly `tl` variables, but also booleans and sequences... For `tl` there's `\c_novalue_tl` for this, ain't it? (If I understood your suggestion). I was using it, but I got some "leakages" of it into the stream (probably my fault...), and went back to "existence", which is needed anyway for the other data types.

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, what I described in my first comment is exactly the principle of `\c_novalue_tl` (which I completely forgot about :).  For sequences, you can differentiate an empty sequence from a sequence with an empty item.  Booleans are harder :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yeah, between a rock and a hard place.  ;-)  I think I will comply. Mas estou contrariado...  Thanks again!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Done! Now I gotta stay away from the site for some time, not to find out about anything else I had done wrong. ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs _Never_ ask me to nitpick :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I didn't! hahaha

Answer (score 0):

For reference, below is the current (as of 2022-02-10) corrected version:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2020-10-01]
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {crefthe}
  {2022/02/10} {}
  {Cross referencing with proper definite articles}

\keys_define:nn { crefthe }
  {
    , overwrite .bool_set:N = \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
    , overwrite .initial:n  = { false }
    , unknown .code:n       =
      { \PassOptionsToPackage { \CurrentOption } { cleveref } }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { crefthe }

\RequirePackage { cleveref }

\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_cref_original:w     \cref
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_Cref_original:w     \Cref
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_crefname_original:w \crefname
\NewCommandCopy \crefthe_Crefname_original:w \Crefname

\str_new:N \l__crefthe_tmpa_str

% \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl is for the "-" mode,
% that only passes the preposition to the first definite article;
% \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl is for the "+" mode,
% that passes the preposition to every definite article.
\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl
\tl_new:N \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl

\bool_new:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 { #4 } { #5 } \crefthe_cref_original:w
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthe { s t- t+ O{} m }
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
    \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 { #4 } { #5 } \crefthe_Cref_original:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__crefthe_cref_general:NNNnnN #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6
  {
    \bool_if:NTF #2
      { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 } }
      {
        \bool_if:NTF #3
          { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl { #4 } }
          {
            % \str_set:Nx fully expands \__crefthe_prep_mode: into a
            % string, then \str_case:Vn compares the value of the
            % resulting string:
            \str_set:Nx \l__crefthe_tmpa_str { \__crefthe_prep_mode: }
            \str_case:Vn \l__crefthe_tmpa_str
              {
                { - } { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #4 } }
                { + } { \tl_set:Nn \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl  { #4 } }
              }
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF #1
      { #6 * { #5 } } % here #6 is \crefthe_cref_original:w or \crefthe_Cref_original:w
      { #6   { #5 } }
    \tl_gclear:N \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
  }

% \__crefthe_prep_mode: defines the default mode for supported languages
\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_prep_mode:
  {
    \str_case:Vn \languagename
      {
        {french}        { + }
        {italian}       { + }
        {spanish}       { - }
        {portuguese}    { + }
        {brazilian}     { + }
      }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
      c \crefthe_crefname_original:w
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \Crefthename { m O{} m O{} m }
  {
    \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 }
      C \crefthe_Crefname_original:w
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__crefthe_name_general:nnnnnNN #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7
  {
    % #6 is c or C
    % #7 is \crefthe_crefname_original:w or \crefthe_Crefname_original:w
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
      {
        #7 { #1 } { #3 } { #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format:nnn } { ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn } { ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
      {
        #7 { #1 } { \crefthemark { #2 } #3 } { \crefthemark { #4 } #5 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format:nnn } { \crefthemark { #2 } ##2 #3 ~ ##1 ##3 }
        \cs_set:cn { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn } { \crefthemark { #4 } ##2 #5 ~ ##1 ##3 }
      }
    \hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument } { crefthe }
      {
        \cs_set_eq:cc { #6ref@ #1 @format } { #6ref_#1_format:nnn }
        \cs_set_eq:cc { #6ref@ #1 @format@first } { #6ref_#1_format_first:nnn }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \text_lowercase:n { V }
\NewDocumentCommand \crefthemark { m }
  {
    \crefthe_contraction:Ve \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
      { \crefthe_contraction:Vn \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl { #1 } }
    \tl_gclear:N \l__crefthe_prep_once_tl
    \tl_set:Nx \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl
      { \text_lowercase:V \l__crefthe_prep_each_tl }
    \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_tail:n { #1 } } { ' } { ~ }
    \bool_set_false:N \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_case_e:nn { nv } { T, F, TF }
\cs_new:Npn \crefthe_contraction:nn #1#2
  {
    \exp_args:Ne \__crefthe_contraction:nnn
      { \text_lowercase:n { #2 } } { #1 } { #2 }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \crefthe_contraction:nn { V, Ve }
\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_contraction:nnn #1 #2 #3
  {
    % #1 is \text_lowercase:n { #3 }
    % #2 is the preposition
    \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
      { #3 }
      {
        \tl_if_exist:cTF { c_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
          {
            \exp_args:Ne \__crefthe_conditional_uppercase:n
              {
                \str_case_e:nvF { #2~#1 }
                  { c_crefthe_contraction_rule_ \languagename _tl }
                  { #2~#1 }
              }
          }
          { #2~#3 }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__crefthe_conditional_uppercase:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__crefthe_uppercase_bool
      { \text_titlecase_first:n }
      { \use:n }
        { #1 }
  }

\hook_gput_code:nnn { begindocument/end } { crefthe }
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l__crefthe_overwrite_bool
      {
        \RenewCommandCopy \cref     \crefthe
        \RenewCommandCopy \Cref     \Crefthe
        \RenewCommandCopy \crefname \crefthename
        \RenewCommandCopy \Crefname \Crefthename
      }
  }

\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_french_tl
  {
    { à~le   }     { au  }
    { à~les  }     { aux }
    { de~le  }     { du  }
    { de~les }     { des }
    { À~le   }     { Au  }
    { À~les  }     { Aux }
    { De~le  }     { Du  }
    { De~les }     { Des }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_italian_tl
  {
    { a~il   }     { al    }
    { a~lo   }     { allo  }
    { a~l'   }     { all'  }
    { a~la   }     { alla  }
    { di~il  }     { del   }
    { di~lo  }     { dello }
    { di~l'  }     { dell' }
    { di~la  }     { della }
    { da~il  }     { dal   }
    { da~lo  }     { dallo }
    { da~l'  }     { dall' }
    { da~la  }     { dalla }
    { in~il  }     { nel   }
    { in~lo  }     { nello }
    { in~l'  }     { nell' }
    { in~la  }     { nella }
    { su~il  }     { sul   }
    { su~lo  }     { sullo }
    { su~l'  }     { sull' }
    { su~la  }     { sulla }
    { a~i    }     { ai    }
    { a~gli  }     { agli  }
    { a~le   }     { alle  }
    { di~i   }     { dei   }
    { di~gli }     { degli }
    { di~le  }     { delle }
    { da~i   }     { dai   }
    { da~gli }     { dagli }
    { da~le  }     { dalle }
    { in~i   }     { nei   }
    { in~gli }     { negli }
    { in~le  }     { nelle }
    { su~i   }     { sui   }
    { su~gli }     { sugli }
    { su~le  }     { sulle }
    { A~il   }     { Al    }
    { A~lo   }     { Allo  }
    { A~l'   }     { All'  }
    { A~la   }     { Alla  }
    { Di~il  }     { Del   }
    { Di~lo  }     { Dello }
    { Di~l'  }     { Dell' }
    { Di~la  }     { Della }
    { Da~il  }     { Dal   }
    { Da~lo  }     { Dallo }
    { Da~l'  }     { Dall' }
    { Da~la  }     { Dalla }
    { In~il  }     { Nel   }
    { In~lo  }     { Nello }
    { In~l'  }     { Nell' }
    { In~la  }     { Nella }
    { Su~il  }     { Sul   }
    { Su~lo  }     { Sullo }
    { Su~l'  }     { Sull' }
    { Su~la  }     { Sulla }
    { A~i    }     { Ai    }
    { A~gli  }     { Agli  }
    { A~le   }     { Alle  }
    { Di~i   }     { Dei   }
    { Di~gli }     { Degli }
    { Di~le  }     { Delle }
    { Da~i   }     { Dai   }
    { Da~gli }     { Dagli }
    { Da~le  }     { Dalle }
    { In~i   }     { Nei   }
    { In~gli }     { Negli }
    { In~le  }     { Nelle }
    { Su~i   }     { Sui   }
    { Su~gli }     { Sugli }
    { Su~le  }     { Sulle }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_spanish_tl
  {
    { a~el  }      { al  }
    { de~el }      { del }
    { A~el  }      { Al  }
    { De~el }      { Del }
  }
\tl_const:Nn \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_portuguese_tl
  {
    { a~o   }      { ao  }
    { a~a   }      { à   }
    { a~os  }      { aos }
    { a~as  }      { às  }
    { de~o  }      { do  }
    { de~a  }      { da  }
    { de~os }      { dos }
    { de~as }      { das }
    { em~o  }      { no  }
    { em~a  }      { na  }
    { em~os }      { nos }
    { em~as }      { nas }
    { A~o   }      { Ao  }
    { A~a   }      { À   }
    { A~os  }      { Aos }
    { A~as  }      { Às  }
    { De~o  }      { Do  }
    { De~a  }      { Da  }
    { De~os }      { Dos }
    { De~as }      { Das }
    { Em~o  }      { No  }
    { Em~a  }      { Na  }
    { Em~os }      { Nos }
    { Em~as }      { Nas }
  }
\tl_const:Nx \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_brazilian_tl
  { \exp_not:V \c_crefthe_contraction_rule_portuguese_tl }

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `crefthe.sty'.
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to fix point 16 from my answer (that I just added)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh, too bad I have uploaded this version to CTAN. I will correct it in the next version, hopefully this won't cause serious trouble to the user (though I suspect if there is actually anyone besides myself that uses this package in the document)

Comment: No problem, probably no user will notice that.  The wrong variant is generated silently if debugging is off, and debugging should be on only while you are writing/testing your package